# Trying to display hidden label if two arrays of object.string is the same on tableView. but i keep getting index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

```
for _ in game[indexPath.row].firstTeam {
            if fireArray[indexPath.row].teams == game[indexPath.row].firstTeam {
                cell.picksAvailable.isHidden = false
                break;
            }

        }
        return cell
```

i'm trying to unhide this label if those array[indexPath.row].String is the same but i keep on getting out of range.
is there a better way to do this

Comment: What are you iterating in the `for` loop? Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to see if a specific element of type string in game array is equal or the same as fireArray.. if that’s the case I want to show the label that’s hidden

Comment: What is the value of `game[indexPath.row].firstTeam`? The code you have posted indicates it is an array, but an array of what? Strings? Then inside your loop neither `fireArray[indexPath.row].teams` nor `game[indexPath.row].firstTeam` will ever change, because you're not modifying `indexPath.row`.

Comment: The values are strings but both array will never have the same object count .. fireArray will always be less than game array

Comment: @MarcMichel - you need to provide much more detail, because it still doesn't make any sense.  With your code, if you select Row 0... let's suppose `game[indexPath.row].firstTeam` is an array of 4 strings. Your loop is effectively *loop 4 times and see if* `fireArray[0].teams == game[0].teams` ... why would you want to compare the same thing 4 times? Post enough of your code so we can see what your variables are and what you're trying to compare.

Comment: Yes I’ll be posting it later I’m at work.. and yea I’m not trying to loop 4 time.. I’m just not experienced enough to know what to do In this situation.. for instance let’s say array1=[“a”, “b”, “c”]
Array2=[“b”].. what I want to do is if array2[“b”]string is the same as array1[“b”] then I want to cell.label.ishidden = false. On whatever cell that contains the b string value

Comment: Do you want to see if there are any common elements in both arrays?  Or do you want want to see if all elements of one array are also in the other array? Or something else?

Comment: I want to see if there is a common element in the array

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer below to check if the two arrays have any common elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check for range before you access the array element:

```swift
if indexPath.row < game.count && indexPath.row < fireArray.count {
    if nil != fireArray[indexPath.row].teams.first(where: game[indexPath.row].firstTeam.contains) {
        cell.picksAvailable.isHidden = false
    }
}
```